# Pass parameter WeakReference<View> to method of ViewModel?

Tags: android, architecture, android-viewmodel

Our teams are debating whether we should pass parameter `WeakReference<View>` to method of `ViewModel` or not. I see in the google's document said

> Note: Since the ViewModel outlives specific activity and fragment instantiations, it should never reference a View, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context. If the ViewModel needs the Application context (for example, to find a system service), it can extend the AndroidViewModel class and have a constructor that receives the Application in the constructor (since Application class extends Context).

How about if we use `WeakReference<View>` to pass view to viewmodel ? WeakRef can prevent the leak memory can occur, however some members said it will make reading/maintain code difficultly. Some guys suggest use interface ViewInf and View will implement to ViewInf and method use in viewmodel will be like that.

```
    fun methodA(viewInf: WeakReference<ViewInf>)() {
        doSomeBackgroundThread(viewInf)
    }
```

We want to use this view to draw on bitmap and use bitmap to save into memcache.

Comment: Don't do that. It would break the dependency and responsibility rule. View is responsible on it's own for drawing the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

The cautionary note from Google makes sense, as the ViewModel is not supposed to do anything other than transport data.

Sometimes we get so caught up in the "object-oriented" part of the design that we forget that domain objects, and application infrastructure objects, should only interact to extract data from,  or inject data into the application for processing.